# How to parameterize django aggregation?

Tags: django, aggregation

I want to do something like

`query.annotate(Count('foreign_model_relation', somefield_from_foreign_model=some_value))`

That means, i want to count, how many objects from another queryset are pointing to this object. The difference between using something like filter(in=other_queryset) is, that i would like to combine this in *one* query, to avoid generating one query per object.

Simplified Models:

- Group
- Object

  - group (Group)
- Vote

  - object (Object)
  - up (Boolean)

Now i want to query the up/down count of all Objects for one Group, with one or two queries, not with one/two queries per Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with two queries:

```
YourObject.objects.filter(vote__up=True, group=some_group).annotate(total_votes_up=Count('vote'))
YourObject.objects.filter(vote__up=False, group=some_group).annotate(total_votes_down=Count('vote'))
```

But I think that should exist some more elegante way to do this.

Comment: No, the problem is, this selects all ObjectModel objects, which have at least one up-vote, but counts all VoteModel objects associated to the ObjectModel. Exactly there is my problem. I did experiment a bit with ''.extra(...)'', too. But subqueries from there cannot easily JOIN with fields from the main query.

Comment: You were right. What did NOT work was: `objs=Object.objects.filter(group=mygroup)` and then filtering `objs_up=objs.filter(vote__up=True)`. I thought this should combine into the same query ...